# emacs fill-paragraph does not respond in any mode

Tags: emacs

Somehow, I broke fill-paragraph.  I'm not sure how to debug it.  Here's the behavior: I have an html file with a long line with 100 characters.  I want to fill the line so I hit the trusty M-q.  Nothing.  I inspect the fill-column variable.  It is set to 79 just like I expect.  I put the buffer in text mode.  Still doesn't work.  I try fundamental mode.  Still nothing.  Notably, in python mode i *do* get the expected behavior.  Any advice?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troubleshooting#Half-splitting

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out (knida).  It seems that the line wrapping doesn't work until you have the text in some mark-up.  For example, in HTML mode, this line all by itself will not wrap:

```
This is a long line.  Why won't it wrap?  Who knows.  Maybe today is the day that I will start learning lisp.
```

...and this line won't wrap either:

```
<p>This is a long line.  Why won't it wrap?  Who knows.  Maybe today is the day that I will start learning lisp.
```

...but this line does wrap:

```
<p>This is a long line.  And this line does wrap.  I guess it has something to do with the HTML tags.</p>
```

Comment: All three should wrap. Most likely you have something in your .emacs messing things up.

Comment: Try without your init file: `emacs -Q`. If you don't see the problem that way then bisect your init file recursively until you find the problematic part. Use command `comment-region` to comment and uncomment sections of the file: `C-h f comment-region RET`.